# How to replace names with hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

I am writing to seek some help with my c# replace function below.  the below tags() function, replace the tag's name with hyperlink in a story.  when I call the story() method, i get the  following output:

> The list consists of: ECP 2013-5A C, two slices of HLA 2014-3A D, KEUKA 2013 D, KEUKA 2013-1X D, MVW 2013-1A D, WOODS 2013-10A D, WOODS 2014-11A D and WOODS 2014-11X D. Only one in the past three months – WOODS 2013-10A D at 00 on 00 February.

**However**, when I call the tag() method, i get the following incorrect output:

> The list consists of: HLA 2014-3A D, KEUKA 2013-1X D, WOODS 2013-10A D, WOODS 2014-11X D. Only one in the past three months –

The output from the tags() function, shows missing data (i.e. tags names) and tag's name not being hyper linked correctly (i.e. www.testdomain.com/data.aspx?searchName=HLA 2014-3A D>HLA 2014-3A D,

```
public string tags()
{

    string html = Story();

    DataTable tags = LoadAllTags();

    if (tags.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            html = html.Replace(tags.Rows[i][0].ToString(), 
              "<a href=\"http://www.testdomain.com/data.aspx?SearchName=" + tags.Rows[i][0].ToString() + ">" + tags.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "</a>"
            );
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

Any further advice, as to where I may be going wrong would be very helpful. 
Thank you

Comment: Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to correctly form your hyperlink. Other than that, I really don't understand the question.

Comment: on a side note use `String.Format`, it's a lot cleaner to work with/read: `html = html.Replace(tags.Rows[i][0].ToString(), String.Format("<a href=\"http://www.testdomain.com/data.aspx?SearchName={0}\">{0}</a>", tags.Rows[i][0].ToString()));`

Comment: Try doing `Console.WriteLine(tags.Rows[i][0]);` and let us know what the output shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code properly, it seems that you aren't reading all of the relevant tags in your rows.

Try the following:

```
public string tags()
{
    string url = "http://www.testdomain.com/data.aspx";
    string html = Story();
    DataTable tags = LoadAllTags();

    if (tags.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(var row in tags.Rows)
        {
            foreach(var column in tags.Columns)
            {
                var tag = column.ToString();
                var path = string.Format("{0}?SearchName={1}", url, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tag);
                var link = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", path, tag);
                html = html.Replace(tag, link);
            }
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```